# Can't figure out the mistake in the pointer here?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int* x;
    int* y;
    x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = 42;
    *y = 13;
    y = x;
    return 0;
}
```

Where is the Error  in which line and why.. ? Can't I assign pointer to another pointer. Yes nothing is being printed out in this .. Actually its my homework question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for `y` before assigning value to it.

```
 y = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *y = 13
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is here: `*y = 13;` The problem is that `y` has not been previously assigned (i.e. an undefined behavior).

Switching

```
*y = 13;
y = x;
```

to

```
y = x;
*y = 13;
```

fixes the problem. Obviously, the memory leak of `malloc(sizeof(int))` still remains.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the memory leak of malloc(sizeof(int)) still remains"?From the definitions of memory leak I checked I still fail to see who the memory leak is there and remains in this case.Your explanation will help me understand the whole thing.Thanks.

Comment: @SheerFish For every call of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` in your program there needs to be a corresponding call to `free` to release the allocated memory back to the free store (which is commonly known simply as the "heap memory"). It is a good idea to do so even with the knowledge that the memory would be returned to the operating system upon the program's exit. Adding `free(x);` before the return statement would fix the memory leak problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I really waited for it.Yeah,I know of free() but never really bothered to use it.Maybe I should be very strict about things just like you,when it comes to programming.

Comment: @SheerFish Calling `free` for each `malloc` is a simple matter of discipline - no decision is required there, you just pair a decision of using dynamic memory with a decision of where you are going to free it, and code both at the same time. In programming profession, discipline beats talent (unless talent is itself disciplined), so it is very important not to give oneself any slack when it comes to trivial matters like that.

Comment: @dasblinklight I even have this nasty habit of not using fclose() to close the open files.Will that get me into trouble or it's bad programming practice only?

Comment: @SheerFish There are cases when not calling `fclose` can result in incomplete output (say, when you exit immediately after writing to a file, and do not call `fflush`). In these cases a call to `fclose` could help you avoid the problem. Of course there's no resource leak there, because OS takes care of the file descriptor.

Comment: I will henceforth take care of those minute details like free() and fclose().Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

`y` is a wild pointer, you are assigning `13` to nothing. You need to `malloc()` it, too.

Either use `malloc` like

```
y = malloc(sizeof(int));
*y = 13;
```

or make `y` a stack-variable like

```
int y = 0;
...
y = *x; //copy value from x to y by dereferencing x
```

Comment: What is  y = x; what is this line doing

Comment: If they are both pointers, `y` is assigned the address of the object `x` points to.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pointers,you have to understand one thing : You are not actually allocating memory in the stack,you just create a pointer to something.That something can be anything but we don't really care. We just have to initialize it and we do that by making it point to something. 
There are two ways,the first one is to make it point to a stack variable and the second to make it point to place in the stack,that you allocated using `malloc()`.

The first way:

```
int x; //you create a stack variable
int *ptr; //you create a type int pointer
ptr=&x; //you make ptr point to the adress where 'x' is
```

The second way:

```
int *ptr; //you create a type int pointer
*ptr=malloc(sizeof(int)); you allocate memory for one int
```

The problem with you code above is that you haven't allocated memory for `int *y` and yet you try to save a number there.

Your code could be written like that

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
 int* x;
 int* y;
 x = malloc(sizeof(int));
 y = malloc(sizeof(int));
 //now both pointers point to a place in memory so you can actually save data on them
 *x = 42;
 *y = 13;
 y = x;
 return 0;
}
```

The problem of cource here is that when you make y point to `x` ,you lose the place `y` was pointing and you leave non usable allocating place in the memory.So before making `y` point to `x` you could use `free()`.

```
*y=13;
free(y);
y=x;
```